# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on my code

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error on my code and I can't even find it. I need your help I review all my ending codes and there is nothing more I can find.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="hide"></th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>MiddleName</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    $model_query=mysql_query("select  * from model");
    while($model_rows=mysql_fetch_array($model_query)){ 
    $id=$model_rows['model_id'];
    $fl=$model_rows['firstname'];

    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="hide"><?php echo $candidate_rows['abc']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $candidate_rows['category']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $candidate_rows['firstname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $candidate_rows['lastname']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $candidate_rows['middlename']; ?></td>
        <td><img class="pic" width="40" height="30" src="<?php echo $candidate_rows['Photo']; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you while loop doesn't have a closing `}` add `<?php } ?>` between these: </tr>
    </tbody>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**closs while loop**

```
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while($model_rows=mysql_fetch_array($model_query)){
```

you have that statement, but I cant see a matching `}`

Thats very likely your error, as the loop doesnt know when to end, So getting to the end of the file is unexpected

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the while loop (closing braces is missing).

```
while($model_rows=mysql_fetch_array($model_query)){ 
    $id=$model_rows['model_id'];
    $fl=$model_rows['firstname'];
.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to close your while statement by a closing brackets.
Either, the mysql_* functions are obsolete, you should care about [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).